Django not found in Github actions
I have the following CI pipeline defined in Github Actions. It is using the same container as which the production server is using. The pipeline was running fine last week, but this week it suddenly stopped working. Some observations from the run logs:

We start with upgrading pip, but this doesn't seem to happen
The dependencies are installed correctly, but it gives a warning that pip can be upgraded
Running fake migrations immediately fails with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'.

Any ideas how I can debug this to investigate what is going wrong?
  test_project:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: python:3.11-slim
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 2
      matrix:
        python-version: [ "3.11" ]
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:14
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: postgres
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        options: >-
          --health-cmd "pg_isready -U postgres"
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          pip install -r requirements-test.txt
      - name: Check missing migrations
        run: python project/manage.py makemigrations --check --dry-run --settings project.settings.local
      - name: Run Tests
        run: pytest --cov=project project/

EDIT
When running this (instead of running pip directly), it does work as intended:
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
python -m pip install -r requirements-test.txt


Please show the contents of requirements.txt and requirements-test.txt.

It contains a lot of requirements, one of them being django==5.0.8.

python seems to invoke a different interpreter than what pip installs for. Best is, as you noticed in the edit to synchronize by using python-m pip all the time
